# При изменении окна браузера сбивается верстка

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

```css
.masthead {
  padding: 3em 3em;
  background-color: #0D1B2E;
  color: white;
  /*float:left;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.masthead h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro {
  padding: 2em 2em;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #429890;
  /*float:right;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.intro p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 550px;
}

@media (min-device-width: 992px) and (max-device-width: 1199px) {
  .masthead {
    padding: 3em 3em;
    background-color: #0D1B2E;
    color: white;
    /*float:left;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 550px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .intro {
    padding: 2em 2em;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #429890;
    /*float:right;*/
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 550px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
  <h1 class="header-type">Test Your Typing Speed</h1>
</div>
<article class="intro">
  <p class="type">This is a typing test. Your goal is to duplicate the provided text, EXACTLY, in the field below. The timer starts when you start typing, and only stops when you match this text exactly. Good Luck!</p>
</article>
<!-- .intro -->
```

Вопрос, возможно, глупый, однако бьюсь над ним уже не первый день. Создал макет, сделал медиа-запросы - при проверке на них верстка ведет себя адекватно. Однако если я просто изменяю окно браузера (пробовал также под размеры медиа-запросов, та же история), то некоторые блоки ведут себя некорректно. В чем причина, что я не учитываю? При необходимости могу выложить код, но чувствую, что упускаю какую-то базовую вещь.

Comment: Приложите пример что и при каких условиях не так

Comment: У тебя есть ряд медиа запросов. Каждый из медиазапросов срабатывает при определенном разрешении экрана. В чем трудность написать стили для отображения отдельного блока при отображении на определенном экране?

Comment: @Kyper я это и сделал, при проверке через адаптивную верстку Chrome все ок, при уменьшении окна браузера структура ломается.

Comment: @MikhailLadonkin Нужно видеть вашу верстку

Comment: Ты упускаешь только ОДНУ базовую вещь - не выложил код... Ну а навскидку верстка однозначно корявая, я с таким поведением ни разу не сталкивался НА СВОИХ верстках...

Comment: @Kyper добавил верстку. Если убрать margin-right и margin-left то все встает на свои места,только между ними появляется просвет, единственное - по какой-то причине они становятся больше родительского блока при уменьшении окна браузера (понимаю, что с этим вообще косяк и криво, но другого решения не нашел)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что не так, но если у блоков intro и masthead убрать max-width то bg становиться на всю ширину, а h1 и p центрируются